# Java Strange modPow() behaviour

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I'm writing a chatting program that uses RSA to login. Theoretically the server creates a random token of 32 bytes as a byte array and encrypts it with the public RSA key of the user and sends it to him, at this point the user decrypts it with his private key and he sends it back to the serevr, in the end the server compares the token generated and the one received from the user.

The problem i noticed is that sometimes when the server encrypts the token the length of the resultant byte array is of 512 bytes and login fails but when it goes all good the the length of the byte array is about 160 bytes.

```
public byte[] encode(byte[] toEncode) {
    byte[] encoded;
    BigInteger y=new BigInteger(toEncode);

    y=y.modPow(new BigInteger(""+encodingPublicKey.getE()), encodingPublicKey.getN());
    encoded=y.toByteArray();

    return encoded;
}
```

This is the code, i can work out a solution for this problem but i'd like to know if i'm doing something wrong

Comment: how can you create new BigInteger with string ?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but it works. With this method i managed to create a encrypted connection between two hosts

Comment: You should use the other constructor for `BigInteger`: `BigInteger(int signum, byte[] magnitude)` with `signum` always being `1`.

Comment: I've just tried using that constructor and now the problem is half solved, the byte array is of the right length but my code is not decrypting properly

Comment: You are doing the insecure textbook RSA rather than the secure OAEP version of RSA.  Implementing your own crypto...  You're going to get yourself into trouble!

Comment: @S.Bacco right, but the problem described in the question is solved and for the rest we obviously don't have enough input - if we would want to do the debugging in the first place. 512 bits sounds like the wrong key (of size 4096 bits instead of 1280 bits).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes you're right, thank you all